# Is it possible to customize the look of Twitter Block?

Tags: theming, social-network

Is it possible to customize the look of the Twitter Block module block?

More specifically, I would just like to change the header of the block which by default says "Tweets" and a Follow button. I'd like to maybe add a background image and put different text where that header is.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation regarding this. All I've come across is this snippet from 3 years ago about editing template.php: https://drupal.org/node/1118306
but I don't know if this is still relevant with the current version and whether if that is the solution I'm looking for.

I've also come across this tool called customize-twitter-1.1: https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1
but also not sure whether this would apply to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can change anything you want via https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7

Comment: What module generates that block?